# The standard matrix [T] of T and if T is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[Picture of Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZ5vT.png)

I'm not really good at formatting, so i did the next best thing.

I'm not quite sure where to start in this question, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: figure out the image of the standard basis.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The columns of $[T]$ are $T\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)$ and $T\left(\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0\\1\end{smallmatrix}\right]\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard matrix of $T$, is $[T]$ such that $$T(v)=w\iff [T]\cdot v=w$$here we have $$T\left(\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\iff [T]\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$therefore $$[T]=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-3&-2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\-2&-3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4&7\\-1&-1\end{bmatrix}$$which is invertible and we obtain$$[T^{-1}]=[T]^{-1}={1\over 3}\begin{bmatrix}-1&-7\\1&4\end{bmatrix}$$